# Can i run macOS Mojave on Virtual Machine Core i5 Windows 10 Home

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, virtual-machine, macos-mojave

I want to start iOS development. Just wondering can i run macOS Mojave on Virtual Machine on Windows 10 Home for building iOS Apps.

My laptop Specification:
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-4200M 3M Cache, up to 3.10 GHz
RAM: 16GB DDR3 1600MHz
Hard Disk: 1TB 5400 RPM
OS: Windows 10 Home

Comment: It can run but you will hate every second doing it and I haven't hear of a single person that was able to ship an app. Instead of doing virtual machine try to run OSX. Google Hackintosh project.

Comment: I'm not shipping an App to store, Just getting started to learn iOS Swift and practicing. You say ''you will hate every second doing it'' why? Is it because it runs slow on my specification or any other reason?

Comment: Slow and you even have HDD. So it will be extremly slow. Try hackintosh. Upgrade to SSD to be up to date. If you are a CS student or work most of the time with computer this is a must.

Comment: What is hackintosh? Can i run hackintosh on my Laptop?

Comment: Please use google, this is not meant to be 1 to 1 support

Comment: OK Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that you probably don't want to hear is that you cannot legally run MacOs on hardware that is not an Apple Mac, not even on a virtual machine. See section 2 B iii of the macOS Mojave license agreement that you can find here: https://www.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macOS1014.pdf